# Troubleshooting slowness in Azure App services

Tags: azure, performance, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

How can I troubleshoot the slowness of my Azure App Service with a microservices architecture and separate databases for each API? The CPU and memory usage on the Azure App Service plan seems normal(Premium PV3), but clients are experiencing slowness during production hours.

I want to investigate the root cause of the slowness in more detail, runtime.

> Although APIs are already integrated with Azure Application Insight,
> providing performance and failure information

but when client reports that the system is slow,
what measures should I take to identify the bottleneck causing the slowness, whether it's at the API level or the database level.

Comment: Throwing ideas: 1. Identify the APIs getting slower (by their response time) to (hopefully) reduce the search scope. 2. Check the affected DB ressource usage (DTU / CPU / IO / LOG), if one gets up to 100%, that could be a cause of slowness, try and scale up those to see if that helps. 3. If the databases you're using support it, try and get the requests execution time. If some take much more time without resources being hogged, you may have lock issues.

Comment: @Irwene, just for information we are using Azure SQL Manage Instance, so in this case what should I do to monitor the DBs?

Comment: I'd start with DTU% if that's how you're purchasing it, if not, then I'd look at CPU%/DATA IO%/LOG IO%, those metrics should show you if you're hitting a resource bottleneck in the DBs. You might also want to monitor for deadlocks if we assume a design issue instead of a resource one.

Comment: And less about monitoring but more about understanding, if you manage to identify if the slowdown is related to a DB and isolate a DB in particular, the query performance insight tool of the database ressource is quite useful to get an idea of what's causing issues.

Comment: Matrices of CPU%/DATA IO%/LOG IO% for SQL MI are all under controlled, the point is not able to figure out  either its SQL MI level issue or its API (code) level issue and all apis are under same azure app service plan also not able to figure that which specific api creating the burden of whole system,

Comment: Well then, I fear I can't help anymore, as I've reached the end of what I know to do in those cases. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check slowness of your Web app and troubleshoot it, ***Visit Diagnose and Solve problems tab > Availability and Performance > Web App Slow***:-

[image]

[image]

You can also check **`High CPU Analysis`** here:-

[image]

For Azure SQL in detail troubleshooting, Refer my [SO answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77176703/sql-azure-bad-query-performance-despite-being-well-under-dtu-limit/77185364#77185364) and [SO answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190909/azure-sql-db-p4-not-scaling-properly/75191688#75191688).